# 10 Points Per Mob Hit

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a server and i am making two call of duty zombies maps for them which are going to be fully functional. But there is a problem with my POINTS scoreboard command. I get 100 points per mob i kill which is what i want but i would like the player to receive 10 POINTS Per mob hit with say an arrow or sword. I made the "100 Points Per Kill Scoreboard" with this tutorial :

http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/348012-points-system-in-minecraft

and im trying to do the "10 points per hit with this tutorial :
http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/2085104-command-block-point-for-each-it

I noticed this is a post from 2013 and wonder if it is outdated.
On the first page there is a video which is the main thing i followed and that's the exact same way i tried to do it on the second tutorial. If you can help that would be amazing thanks!

Comment: Why does he get downvotes?

Comment: Me? People just do as far as i know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about what entity they hit, you could do this:

Add a scoreboard called "Attack" using stat.damageDealt using:

`/scoreboard objectives add Attack stat.damageDealt`

And then creating this chain of command blocks:

[image]  [image]

```
     Repeating: /scoreboard players add @a[score_Attack_min=1] Points 10
     Chain: /scoreboard players set @a[score_Attack_min=1] Attack 0
```

This will basically add 10 to the "Points" variable every time the player deals a single point of damage. Keep in mind that stat.damageDealt doesn't count up by ones, but by the amount of damage actually dealt (ie. 16), so if they somehow do damage faster than 20x per second, it won't count every single hit.

Additionally, if you only want it to go up when the player attacks a zombie, you could use the score of:
`stat.killEntity.Zombie`

Comment: Multiple problems. Instead of 10 "POINTS" it gives me "100" and it does not count damage of arrows which will be main Weapon (forgot it was an Entity so the "Player" did not damage the thing. If you know another fix that would be helpfull.

Comment: Sorry it was my own fault it was not working (still had old tutorials machine running and they conflicted) but an arrow will still not add any points . Is there something like arrow.damagedealt ?

Comment: You could possibly add a tag to arrows when they are in a radius of 1 of a player that has a stat.useItem.minecraft:bow score, and then execute the arrow and when it goes in a radius of 1 of a zombie, change the score by 10 and then immediately kill the arrow. I'm not completely sure why it goes up by 100; try setting it to 1 instead of 10.

Comment: ok thanks i fixed the 100 issue (my fault) And i think that i've found a kind of loophole which has nothing to do with redstone. Your answer was pretty much the corrrect answer with the only prob being the arrow entity